# failing pipeline with a valid jenkins script "No such static method found: staticMethod"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i am trying to implement jenkins script for monitoring slaves agents
following this article: "https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/nodes/"
i ran this script in the jenkins script consul successfully but i keep failing when i run it inside a pipeline

```
import hudson.node_monitors.*
import hudson.slaves.*
import java.*
import javax.activation.*
import thread.*
import java.lang.*


def getEnviron(computer) {
   def env
   def thread = Thread.start("Getting env from ${computer.name}", { env = computer.environment })
   thread.join(2000)
   if (thread.isAlive()) thread.interrupt()
   env
}

def slaveAccessible(computer) {
    getEnviron(computer)?.get('PATH') != null
}


def numberOfflineNodes = 0
def numberNodes = 0

pipeline {
    parameters {
         string(name: 'Slack_channel',
           description: 'OTT DevOps channel',
           defaultValue: '#ott-devops-team')
    }
    environment {
   // Slack configuration
   SLACK_COLOR_DANGER  = '#E01563'
   SLACK_COLOR_INFO    = '#6ECADC'
   SLACK_COLOR_UNSTABLE    = '#E01563'
   SLACK_COLOR_WARNING = '#FFC300'
   SLACK_COLOR_GOOD    = '#3EB991'
   }


    agent {label "master"}
    stages {
        stage('monitor and restart slave agents') {
            steps {
                script {


                    def jenkins = Hudson.instance

                    for (slave in jenkins.slaves) {
                       def computer = slave.computer
                       numberNodes ++
                       println ""
                       println "Checking computer ${computer.name}:"
                       def isOK = (slaveAccessible(computer) && !computer.offline)
                       if (isOK) {
                         println "\t\tOK, got PATH back from slave ${computer.name}."
                         println('\tcomputer.isOffline: ' + slave.getComputer().isOffline());
                         println('\tcomputer.isTemporarilyOffline: ' + slave.getComputer().isTemporarilyOffline());
                         println('\tcomputer.getOfflineCause: ' + slave.getComputer().getOfflineCause());
                         println('\tcomputer.offline: ' + computer.offline);


                       } else {
                         numberOfflineNodes ++
                         println "  ERROR: can't get PATH from slave ${computer.name}."
                         println('\tcomputer.isOffline: ' + slave.getComputer().isOffline());
                         println('\tcomputer.isTemporarilyOffline: ' + slave.getComputer().isTemporarilyOffline());
                         println('\tcomputer.getOfflineCause: ' + slave.getComputer().getOfflineCause());
                         println('\tcomputer.offline: ' + computer.offline);
                         if (slave.getComputer().isTemporarilyOffline()) {
                          if (!slave.getComputer().getOfflineCause().toString().contains("Disconnected by")) {
                             computer.setTemporarilyOffline(false, slave.getComputer().getOfflineCause())
                          }
                         } else {
                             computer.connect(true)
                         }
                       }
                     }
                    println ("Number of Offline Nodes: " + numberOfflineNodes)
                    println ("Number of Nodes: " + numberNodes)
                }
            }
        }
    }
   post {
   aborted {
     echo "Sending message to Slack"
     slackSend (color: "${env.SLACK_COLOR_WARNING}",
                channel: "${params.Slack_channel}",
                message: "*ABORTED:* Job ${env.JOB_NAME} build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} \n More info at: ${env.BUILD_URL}")
   } // aborted
   unstable {
     echo "Sending message to Slack"
     slackSend (color: "${env.SLACK_COLOR_UNSTABLE}",
                channel: "${params.Slack_channel}",
                message: "*UNSTABLE:* Job ${env.JOB_NAME} build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} \n More info at: ${env.BUILD_URL} in ${params.ENV}")
   } // unstable
   failure {
     echo "Sending message to Slack"
     slackSend (color: "${env.SLACK_COLOR_DANGER}",
                channel: "${params.Slack_channel}",
                message: "*FAILED:* Job ${env.JOB_NAME} build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} \n More info at: ${env.BUILD_URL} ")
   } // failure
   success {
     echo "Sending message to Slack"
     slackSend (color: "${env.SLACK_COLOR_GOOD}",
                channel: "${params.Slack_channel}",
                message: "*SUCCESS:* Job ${env.JOB_NAME} build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} \n More info at: ${env.BUILD_URL} ")
   } // success
  } // post
}
```

the error code is:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such static method found: staticMethod java.lang.Thread start org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onStaticCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:182)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:187)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedStaticCall(Checker.java:191)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:98)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.getEnviron(WorkflowScript:12)
    at WorkflowScript.slaveAccessible(WorkflowScript:19)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:56)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:84)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor307.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

using the same script inside the http://jenkins_home/script is working fine
there is no waiting approval requests in the /scriptApproval/

Answer (score 0):

The exception comes from the script security plugin.

You will see under Manage Jenkins -> In-process Script Approval (or surf to `<your-jenkins-host>/scriptApproval`) the line(s) you need to approve in order to run the script.

If there are multiple offending lines you will need to repeat this process until all security requirements are satisfied.

Another way is to disable the groovy sandbox in the pipeline altogether (right under the script box when you configure the pipeline), but unless you're testing it's best to leave it ticked.

Comment: hi
i configured it without sandbox but its still failing for the same reason
i done have any requests in the /scriptApproval as well

Comment: For the sake of the experiment you can disable the script security plugin temporarily, because this is the source of the exception (maybe a bug in the version you have?). Then you can re-run the pipeline and see if the build's output is any different